# Config files not being read

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cron, services, vsftpd

This is a super issue weird that I cannot for the life of me figure out, so would be very grateful for assistance.

My home server is an old Mac-Mini with 2 external HDD's in RAID1 using mdadm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.

For both Cron and VSFTPD (+ I also recall having a similar issue when attempting to setup a WireGuard server, but didn't realise it was related at the time)
I have found that editing configuration files makes no difference to the behavior of the software, for example at the moment attempting to setup VSFTPD for SFTP access, I am editing the configuration file to chroot the user to their home directory, but with no avail.

The service is running for both cron and vsftpd, I have restarted the service using `sudo service cron/vsftpd restart` and also checked the status which shows no errors, but the changes are not reflected in the behaviour of the application.

Additionally, when I add nonsense lines the the config files (strings of random text that are not commands, e.g. "fjkdshfgksd") and restart the service, it does in fact cause the service to fail, in both cron and vsftpd.

(the config files are at /etc/vsftpd.conf and /etc/crontab respectively, and the /etc directory is owned by root.)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"*attempting to setup VSFTPD for SFTP access*" - vsftpd doesn't do SFTP. It's an FTP server - totally different protocol.

- FTP - unencrypted (should be obsolete) based around ports 20/21. Data transfers are controlled from the opposite end of the connection to the control channel, leading to complex management in firewalls. TLS extensions for to the protocol provide FTP/S for encryption.
- SFTP - encrypted by design layered on top of SSH on port 22.

If you want to configure SFTP service, remove `vsftpd` completely as you don't need it. Then configure SFTP in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: wha-
um
ok, my bad i guess - thanks!
i thought sftp was just regular ftp but stuck thru an SSH tunnel...

this still doesn't explain the behavior with cron and wireguard configs doing absolutely nothing though?

Comment: @proton no it doesn't, but you haven't provided any detail for us to grab hold of the issue